# Order relationship with respect to n^(nmod6)

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, relationship

What is the order relationship between f(n) = 10n and g(n) = n^(nmod6)?

I know that I can think of f(n) as just n, but thinking about g(n) confuses me because won't nmod6 change with the different values of n? For example, n = 6 would make g(n) = n^0 = 1 but when n = 5, g(n) = n ^ 5. How can I think of this with respect to the Big-Oh, Big-Theta, and Big-Omega relationships?

Answer (score 0):

(n mod 6) can only take values from 0 to 5, so g(n) is bounded above by n^5, and bounded below by 1. So it would be O(n^5) and Omega(1). It does not have a workable Big-Theta.